# Room reset incremental key after deleting data

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

How can I set the id (which is my `@PrimaryKey(autogenerate = true)`) back to 0 after I have deleted all data in Room Database Table? For the moment my delete works but the new inserted data increment where the last ID has been.

Comment: VACUUM? If all data is deleted, then you should definitely run a vacuum on your database.

Comment: You could drop the primary key column, re-create and all the ids should then be reassigned in order. However this is probably a bad idea in most situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Dao
interface MyDao {

 @RawQuery
 fun vacuumDb(supportSQLiteQuery: SupportSQLiteQuery): Int
}
```

When all of the content is deleted, execute this statement,

```
MyDao.vacuumDb(SimpleSQLiteQuery("VACUUM"))
```

VACUUM command does not change the content of your database but changes **rowids**. This will reset the **rowids**.

### How VACUUM works?

> The VACUUM command works by copying the contents of the database into a temporary database file and then overwriting the original with the contents of the temporary file. When overwriting the original, a rollback journal or write-ahead log WAL file is used just as it would be for any other database transaction. This means that when VACUUMing a database, as much as twice the size of the original database file is required in free disk space.
>
> The VACUUM INTO command works the same way except that it uses the file named on the INTO clause in place of the temporary database and omits the step of copying the vacuumed database back over top of the original database.
>
> The VACUUM command may change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables that do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.
>
> A VACUUM will fail if there is an open transaction on the database connection that is attempting to run the VACUUM. Unfinalized SQL statements typically hold a read transaction open, so the VACUUM might fail if there are unfinalized SQL statements on the same connection. VACUUM (but not VACUUM INTO) is a write operation and so if another database connection is holding a lock that prevents writes, then the VACUUM will fail.
>
> An alternative to using the VACUUM command to reclaim space after data has been deleted is auto-vacuum mode, enabled using the auto_vacuum pragma. When auto_vacuum is enabled for a database free pages may be reclaimed after deleting data, causing the file to shrink, without rebuilding the entire database using VACUUM. However, using auto_vacuum can lead to extra database file fragmentation. And auto_vacuum does not compact partially filled pages of the database as VACUUM does.

More info: [SQLite VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)

Comment: can I mark it as suspend since I'm using `Room` with coroutines?

Comment: `The VACUUM command may change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables that do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.` But I do have an explicit Integer Primary Key

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher Personally never used coroutines with this statement. My guess is that you should be able to mark it as a suspended considering it's IO intensive task. What they mean is that VACUUM command is not necessarily going to ignore implicit Primary Keys, it MAY change them as well.